# Conv2D transpose output shape using formula

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I get `[-1,256,256,3]` as the output shape using the transpose layers shown below. I print the output shape. My question is specifically about the height and width which are both `256`. The channels seem to be the number of filters from the last transpose layer in my code.

I assumed rather simplistically that the formula is this. I read other threads.

```
H = (H1 - 1)*stride + HF - 2*padding
```

But when I calculate I don't seem to get that output. I think I may be missing the padding calculation
  How much padding is added by `'SAME'` ?

My code is this.

```python
    linear = tf.layers.dense(z, 512 * 8 * 8)
    linear  = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(linear, is_training=is_training,decay=0.88)
    conv = tf.reshape(linear, (-1, 128, 128, 1))
    out = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(conv, 64,kernel_size=4,strides=2, padding='SAME')
    out = tf.layers.dropout(out, keep_prob)
    out = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(out, is_training=is_training,decay=0.88)
    out = tf.nn.leaky_relu(out)
    out = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(out, 128,kernel_size=4,strides=1, padding='SAME')
    out = tf.layers.dropout(out, keep_prob)
    out = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(out, is_training=is_training,decay=0.88)
    out = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(out, 3,kernel_size=4,strides=1, padding='SAME')
    print( out.get_shape())
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Regarding `'SAME'` padding, the [`Convolution`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/nn#Convolution) documentation offers some detailed explanations (further details in those [notes](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/nn#Notes_on_SAME_Convolution_Padding)). Especially, when using `'SAME'` padding, the output shape is defined so:

> ```
> # for `tf.layers.conv2d` with `SAME` padding:
> out_height = ceil(float(in_height) / float(strides[1]))
> out_width  = ceil(float(in_width) / float(strides[2]))
> ```

In this case, the output shape depends only on the input shape and stride. The padding size is computed from there to fill this shape requirement (while, with `'VALID'` padding, it's the output shape which depends on the padding size)

Now for transposed convolutions... As this operation is the backward counterpart of a normal convolution (its gradient), it means that the output shape of a normal convolution corresponds to the input shape to its counterpart transposed operation. In other words, while the output shape of `tf.layers.conv2d()` is divided by the stride, the output shape
 of `tf.layers.conv2d_transpose()` is multiplied by it:

```
# for `tf.layers.conv2d_transpose()` with `SAME` padding:
out_height = in_height * strides[1]
out_width  = in_width * strides[2]
```

But once again, the padding size is calculated to obtain this output shape, not the other way around (for `SAME` padding). Since the normal relation between those values (i.e. the relation you found) is:

```
# for `tf.layers.conv2d_transpose()` with given padding:
out_height = strides[1] * (in_height - 1) + kernel_size[0] - 2 * padding_height
out_width  = strides[2] * (in_width - 1) + kernel_size[1] - 2 * padding_width
```

Rearranging the equations we get

```
padding_height = [strides[1] * (in_height - 1) + kernel_size[0] - out_height] / 2
padding_width  = [[strides[2] * (in_width - 1) + kernel_size[1] - out_width] / 2
```

> **note:** if e.g. `2 * padding_height` is an odd number, then `padding_height_top = floor(padding_height)`; and `padding_height_bottom = ceil(padding_height)` (same for resp. `padding_width`, `padding_width_left` and `padding_width_right)`

Replacing `out_height` and `out_width` with their expressions, and using your values (for the 1st transposed convolution):

```
padding = [2 * (128 - 1) + 4 - (128 * 2)] / 2 = 1
```

You thus have a padding of `1` added on every side of your data, in order to obtain the output dim `out_dim = in_dim * stride = strides * (in_dim - 1) + kernel_size - 2 * padding = 256`

Comment: Let me calculate for my code. Atleast one other SO thread mislead me. Edited the question.Wasn't aware it is all there in the doc.

Comment: I tried to clarify my answer further. Hope it helps.

Comment: strides * (in_dim - 1) + kernel_size - 2 * padding = 256                    Could you replace this with values ?

Comment: I went to fast yesterday and made a mistake in the equations for `padding_height` & `padding_width`, my bad. It is now corrected, with finally `padding = 1` in your case.
We thus correctly have `out_dim = strides * (in_dim - 1) + kernel_size - 2 * padding = 2 * (128 - 1) + 4 - 2 * 1 = 256`.

Comment: And for the next two transposes this shape(256) doesn't change. You mean ?

Comment: For the next two transposed convolutions, your stride is `1` and you still use `'SAME'` padding. If you apply the formula I shared (e.g. `out_height = in_height * strides[1]`), you'll see the shape stay constant.

Comment: Please try to fix the 'downvote' in my question.I clarified it.

Answer (score 1):

I drew a diagram for myself based on @Aldream's answer. Maybe useful to visualize. Hope I got that right. But I have to research how and where this padding is applied to get the final shape.

[image]