# How does transposed convolution work with same padding in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have been looking at Transposed Convolution with same padding and strides of 2 and something doesn't make sense to me.

Given an input of width and height of 3x3, the output will have a shape 6x6. From what I have read, convolution transposed is just convolution.

So input like

```
    
      
        1 2 3
        4 5 6
        7 8 9
      
    

    will be transformed to the following matrix then convolved on with strides of 1

    
      
        1 0 2 0 3
        0 0 0 0 0
        4 0 5 0 6
        0 0 0 0 0
        7 0 8 0 9
```

Thus the output should have a shape of 5x5, where did the extra column come from ? .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conv2D transpose output shape using formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50683039/conv2d-transpose-output-shape-using-formula)

Comment: @MohanRadhakrishnan so my expansion and of the input matrix and placement of the zeros is correct ?

Comment: @MohanRadhakrishnan ur answer there is incorrect. try solving the equations you have with input size of 5. you will get contradicting numbers

Comment: @Aldream's answer.I was pointing out a possible duplicate. If it is different from what you are asking then you should wait for an answer.