# How Tensorflow Handles 'SAME' padding in transpose convolutional?

Tags: tensorflow, deconvolution

I would like to know how 'SAME' padding is calculated when using a transpose convolutional layer in Tensorflow. I find the way it is calculated in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/nn#convolution) in a convolutional layer with this formula in this link, but I wonder how it is done in the deconvolutional layer. Thanks!

Comment: There is an answer for a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50683039/conv2d-transpose-output-shape-using-formula)