# How to control the output of Transposed convolution layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using keras with tensorflow and at some point I want to apply [`Conv2DTranspose()`](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/) (i.e. erroneously called Deconvolution) to layer so as to add it with another layer having roughly the double size.

To make it more concrete as a problem I am using Single Shot Detector and I want to add the layers `conv3_3` with `conv4_3` which in my network (which is a custom one) have dimensions:

```
conv3_3: 75, 155, x
conv4_3: 38, 78, 2*x
```

so when I apply:

```
conv4_3_trans = Conv2DTranspose(filters=filters[2],  kernel_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', name='conv4_3_deconv')(conv4_3)
```

which gives as an output a layer with dimensions: `76, 156, x` which obviously is 1 pixel off in each dimension. So, naturally the interpreter is complaining about it. I have checked the solution in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50683039/conv2d-transpose-output-shape-using-formula) but the OP there is not interested in getting a layer with specific dimensions.

If I play with `kernel_size` parameter, for example `kernel_size=(1, 1)` does not change the output (it's the same `76, 156, x`). Similarly, `padding='same'` or `padding='valid'` have the same results also.

So, I was wondering if there was any way to control my output using the keras code? Is there something I could use to get the desired output?

One solution I found (which make things a bit more complicated for the consequences in other part of the code) is using a slightly larger image as the original input: instead of using images `(620, 300)` I could use `(624, 304)` which after 2 reductions would give an even number and the `Conv2DTranspose()` would give the same dimensions. Maybe also `UpSampling2D()` could be used but I am interested in the `Conv2DTranspose()` so as to have trainable parameters.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this. The transposed convolution will duplicate the size of your input, because you are using a 2x2 kernel. You can not get an image with size 75x155 with a 2x2 transposed convolution. You can either use a different size of kernel that can produce those dimensions (3x5, 5x5) or, more reasonably, just slice that extra pixel in each dimension out.

Comment: (the previous comment assumes a stride the same size as the kernel, obviously with different stride or dilation values you can get different sizes)