# Calculating output after convolution and transpose convolution

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, deconvolution, generative-adversarial-network

I was going through a research paper to understand **GANs**. As I have recently studied **CNNs** I wanted to determine the output shape at each step after `convolution` and then after `transpose convolution`. The following image describes the *Generator network* as menioned in the paper:

[image]

I know that the formula to calculate *output shape* after convolution is:

`O = (W - K - 2*P)/S + 1`

For calculating the shape of transpose convolution I referred to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50683039/conv2d-transpose-output-shape-using-formula).

The following is the code I have used to calculate the output shapes:

```
# h -> height
# w -> width
# k_h -> kernel height
# k_w -> kernel width
# pad_h -> padding height
# pad_w -> padding width
# s_h -> stride height
# s_w -> stride width
# n_f -> number of filters
def conv2d(h, w, k_h, k_w, pad, s_h, s_w, n_f):
    out_h = math.floor((h - k_h + 2*pad)/s_h) + 1
    out_w = math.floor((w - k_w + 2*pad)/s_w) + 1
    
    print("In (h, w) : ({0}, {1}) -conv2d-> ({2}, {3}, {4})".format(h, w, out_h, out_w, n_f))
    return out_h, out_w 

def conv2dTrans(h, w, k_h, k_w, s_h, s_w, n_f):
    pad_h = math.ceil((s_h*(h - 1) + k_h - h*s_h)/2)
    pad_w = math.ceil((s_w*(w - 1) + k_w - w*s_w)/2)
    
    print("Padding (h, w) : ({0}, {1})".format(pad_h, pad_w))
    
    # out_dim = strides * (in_dim - 1) + kernel_size - 2 * padding
    out_h = ((s_h*(h - 1) + k_h - 2*pad_h))
    out_w = ((s_w*(w - 1) + k_w - 2*pad_w))
    
    print("In (h, w) : ({0}, {1}) -conv2dTranspose-> ({2}, {3}, {4})".format(h, w, out_h, out_w, n_f))
    return out_h, out_w

# Convolution
h, w = conv2d(256, 256, 7, 7, 0, 1, 1, 128)
h, w = conv2d(h, w, 3, 3, 0, 2, 2, 128)
..... and so on
# Transpose Convolution
h, w = conv2dTrans(h, w, 3, 3, 2, 2, 128)
..... and so on
```

I have called the functions in the order as given in the image but the *output shape* of the generator network is not equal to the *input shape* **(256, 256)**.